# Date format for fields inRetrofit requests

Tags: android, datetime, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit for my REST calls. Some call require date in form-urlencoded fields. Using search I found convenient way to use date formatter pattern for JSON body. Just call `.setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy")` on `GsonBuilder`. I'm wondering if there is similar convenient way to set formatter pattern for parameters Retrofit are taking in `@Field`, `@Path` and `@Query` fields.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it supports this right now in some nice way. Check this answer by one of the authors (this deals specifically with the Date issue): https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/291

I have copied the code from the GitHub issue answer here.

```
public class PathDate {
  private static final ThreadLocal<DateFormat> DF = new ThreadLocal<DateFormat>() {
    @Override public DateFormat initialValue() {
      return new SimpleDateFormat("THE FORMAT YOU WANT HERE!!!!");
    }
  }

  private final Date date;

  public PathDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
  }

  @Override public String toString() {
    return DF.get().format(date);
  }
}
```

Now your Retrofit code looks like this

```
@GET("/programs/date/{date}")
void findByDate(@Path("date") PathDate date, Callback<List<Program>> cb);
```

Answer (score 1):

For Retrofit 2 it is possible to set custom Converter.Factory

```
public class QueryConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {
public static QueryConverterFactory create() {
    return new QueryConverterFactory();
}

private QueryConverterFactory() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Converter<?, String> stringConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
    if (type == Date.class) {
        return DateQueryConverter.INSTANCE;
    }
    return null;
}

private static final class DateQueryConverter implements Converter<Date, String> {
    static final DateQueryConverter INSTANCE = new DateQueryConverter();

    private static final ThreadLocal<DateFormat> DF = new ThreadLocal<DateFormat>() {
        @Override
        public DateFormat initialValue() {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        }
    };

    @Override
    public String convert(Date date) {
        return DF.get().format(date);
    }
}
```

}

You can add your own types and converters.